# How can I see what is included in a Windows 10 feature update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates

I am using Windows 10 Pro, version 10.0.15063, build 15063. I have this update notification in the corner of my screen:

[image: Update Notification]

I assume this update is for the latest Creators release, but I'd like to confirm that. How can I see what the update actually is? There don't seem to be any buttons or links for more information about the scheduled update. How can I figure out exactly which updates are pending and will be installed when I restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to get directly at this information from the notification that pops up on the screen. You have to go to the Windows Update settings screen to see exactly which updates are pending.

First, hit the Windows key or click the start button, and type "update settings":

[image]

Hit enter, and you'll see the "Windows Update" settings screen:

[image]

The area within the red box contains information about any pending updates, including the KB# that allows you to look up what the update contains.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I see what the update actually is?

Microsoft publishes and has published similar articles for all the current and yet to be released feature updates.  Some interesting changes of many are the following:

> - Voice-activated Power Commands. In addition to exciting voice-activated features like reaching Cortana above the lock screen, you can now ask Cortana to shut down, restart, or sleep your PC.
> - You may have also noticed a new Microsoft Store logo on your Windows 10 device. We’ve unified the Microsoft Store on both Windows 10 and Xbox for a simpler shopping experience. Microsoft Store – whether shopping in a physical store, online, or through your Xbox or Windows 10 device – is the best destination to seamlessly discover, experience, download and buy the latest products and content from Microsoft and its partners, including hardware, games, entertainment, apps, and more.
> - To better protect against ransomware attacks, we’re introducing Windows Defender Exploit Guard that helps protect files from unauthorized changes by nefarious applications and your applications from unknown exploits. Additionally, Windows Defender Antivirus now has specific safeguards in place, along with default enhanced coverage that is delivered instantly via the cloud protection service. These and other security technologies protect against persistent ransomware campaigns like Cerber, Locky, and Spora, as well as global outbreaks like WannaCry, and Petya.
> - When you save your files in OneDrive, now you can access them just like any other file on your PC without filling up your disk space. Easily tell which files are available online only or offline. Online-only files download on demand with a double-click, and you can make them online only again to free up space
> - No more getting locked out of your device. If you’re using an AADP or MSA account and you get stuck at login, you can now reset your password and PIN straight from the lock screen after verifying your account identity.

[What’s new in the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/10/17/whats-new-windows-10-fall-creators-update/)

> Reading a blog about what's included in the Creators update doesn't help me if I can't confirm that the pending update on my machine is in fact the Creators update.

Windows Update has a way to view pending updates in the update history. Only feature update it could be talking about is the Fall Creators Update considering you are already running the Creators Update.

The feature updates which are uninstalled should be in the list of pending updates, however once they are installed the list of updates is cleared due to Windows 10 being upgraded to that new version of Windows 10.

A feature update will appear in the history as simply “Feature update to Windows 10 version YYMM” at least until Microsoft changes how they are listed.

> I want to know the KB# of the pending update so I can read about it before completing it.

Windows 10 Feature updates do not have KB articles associated with them.  Any changes contained within a feature update is published on the Windows 10 blog which I have already linked to.

**The author of this question changed and/or clarified their question after I submitted this answer I went to a lot of effort to write this answer.**

Comment: There are other changes, far to many to list in this answer, and I would have to literally quote a 3,000+ article.

Comment: I understand that, but that's not what I was looking for. I was looking for a way to see *exactly* which updates are currently pending on my machine. I wanted to know what to expect when I restarted. I've edited the end of the question to clarify that.

Comment: The feature update is a single update.  Your comment doesn’t really make sense.  Windows Update has a way to view pending updates in the update history.  Only feature update it could be talking about is the Fall Creators Update considering you are already running the Creators Update.

Comment: I think you're overthinking my question. A window pops up saying an update is ready. I want to know the KB# of the pending update so I can read about it before completing it. Reading a blog about what's included in the Creators update doesn't help me if I can't confirm that the pending update on my machine is in fact the Creators update.

Comment: Feature updates don’t have KBs, so I can’t provide something, that doesn’t exist.

Comment: I have detailed in extreme details the upgrade process Windows uses once already to another answer to a different question.  Irrelevant to this question asked though.